# java: splitting one array into two separate arrays based on even and odd positions of the array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to Java and I'm having difficulties I have an assignment that requires me to load a text file with the name of a state followed by its capital onto the program and read the state names into one array and the capital names into another array. The way I tackled this was that I loaded the text file into one array called total and made a count. I wanted to split those with an even position to be in a separate array called capital and those in an odd position to be in an array called states. But I'm not sure how exactly to put that into code. This is what I have so far

Sample of Text File:

```
Alabama
Montgomery
Alaska
Juneau
Arizona
Phoenix
Arkansas
Little Rock
California
Sacramento
Colorado
Denver
Connecticut
Hartford
Delaware
Dover
Florida
Tallahassee
Georgia
Atlanta
Hawaii
Honolulu
```

And my code so far

```
public class StateCapitals 
{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.io.FileNotFoundException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        File inputfile;
        File outputfile;
        inputfile = new File("capitals.txt"); 
        outputfile = new File ("InOrder.txt");
        String stateandcity;
        int count;
        count = 1;

        PrintWriter pw;
        Scanner kb;
        kb = new Scanner(inputfile);


         String [] total;
         total = new String[100];

         String [] capitals;
         capitals = new String[50];    

         String [] states;
         states = new String [50];

      while (kb.hasNextLine())
        {
        stateandcity = kb.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Count: " +count + "   " + stateandcity);

        total[count-1] = stateandcity;
         count ++;

        } 

      if (count % 2 == 0)  
          states = new String [50];   //where i need help

    }}
```

Comment: Sample text from the input file would help

Comment: I hope the city and state are separated by a `,`, or else this assignment is needlessly complicated. (Also, you are reading the city and state as 1 String, so you need to split strings, not the array)

Comment: So the text file would have something like: Alabama
Montgomery
Alaska
Juneau
Arizona
Phoenix
Arkansas
Little Rock
California
Sacramento

Comment: All on one line? That way over-complicated for an assignment...

Comment: New lines don't display in comments, try editing your question to include the sample file. Also, if the capitals and states are on the same line, separated by a space, what happens to something like `New York`? How do you decide which part is the state and which part is the capital? Not to mention that currently, the items at even positions are states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm will be like this:

- Read everything into `total` like you have already thought of.
- Use a for loop to loop from i=0 to i=100 (or however many items there are to be split), incrementing by 2 each time.
- Assign `total[i]` to `capital[i / 2]`.
- Assign `total[i + 1]` to `states[i / 2]`.

It is as simple as that! Try doing it yourself first. If you are having difficulties, just leave a comment!

Comment: That won't work. He is reading the city and the state as 1 String, so spitting the array in any way won't separate the state from the city. They need to break apart each line.

Comment: Oh, I guess I am deceived by the lengths of the arrays the OP declared and didn't look at how he is actually reading the file. Editing now. @Tezra

Comment: Sorry, got confused by OP.. I guess roll back your answer =P

Answer (score 0):

I would separate them while reading them like this. (Save yourself a loop)

```
while (kb.hasNextLine())
    {
    state[count] = kb.nextLine();
    capitals[count] = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Count: " +count + "   " +
                        state[count] + "," + 
                        capitals[count]);

    count ++;    
    }
```